# Move data from a table to another table in SQL using some of the first table content as columns of the receiving table

Tags: mysql, database-design

Sorry for the long title, but couldn't find something shorter unfortunately. So my problem is the following, I have been given a SQL table with the following columns:

```
Id_String  |  Date  |  Time  |  Value
```

Id_String is a number that ranges from 101 to 120. Here is a sample of the data:

```
101 1982-12-02  07:48:03    0.001
102 1982-12-02  07:48:04    0.002
102 1982-12-02  07:50:04    0.004
102 1982-12-02  07:52:04    0.006
103 1982-12-02  07:52:05    0.006
```

What I need to do is simple yet I'm not an expert so I'm not sure this can be done in an easy way. I'd like to build a table with the following columns:

```
Date  |  Time  |  Value_Id_String_101  |  Value_Id_String_102 | ... | Value_Id_String_120
```

That is, for each date and time I have all the values of the String Ids. Is there a SQL command that I can run on the first table in order to automatically generate the second table? Or should I write a script that does it "manually"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this mysql, sql server or both?

Comment: MySql is the server I'm running. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I have no idea, you can ask my boss.

Comment: Show us the desired output for that dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Use these query

```
       INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM SOURCE_TABLE;

    or

 CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```